# Confidence interval for estimating probability of a biased coin

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory

Suppose we have a coin with an unknown probability $p$ of coming up heads and that of $1-p$ of coming up tails.

Now, we repeatedly flip the coin $n$ times and record the results, heads turn up $X$ time, then we could estimate $p$ with $\hat p = X/n$.

The problem is how close $\hat p$ is to $p$. For example, if we already know $0.4≤p≤0.6$, to obtain an estimate of $\hat p$ that is within $5\%$ of the real $p$, i.e.

$$0.95p \le \hat p \le 1.05 p$$

how large does $n$ need to be if we want to ensure the probability the above confidence interval is at least 0.95? i.e.

$$\mathbb{P}[0.95p \le \hat p \le 1.05p] \ge 0.95$$

Comment: How can $p$ be larger than $1$???

Comment: @barakmanos, $p$ is within [0.4, 0.6], so $1.05p$ is still less than 1. The question never says $p$ is larger than 1.

Comment: @zyxue Even if 1.05p > 1, that just means P[0.95p < p^hat < 1.05p] = P[0.95p < p^hat], which is still a valid expression. So p being within [0.4, 0.6] isn't a necessary condition for the expression to make logical sense.

Answer (score 6):

Let $X_i$ be $1$ if the $i$-th flip is a head and $X_i = 0$ if the $i$-th flip is a tail.

The $X_i$'s are i.i.d. $\text{Bernoulli}(p)$. Hence, $E[X_i] = p$ and $\text{Var}[X_i] = p(1-p)$.

Our estimate for $p$ is given by $\hat{p} = \dfrac{1}{n}\displaystyle\sum_{i = 1}^{n}X_i$.

By linearity, $E[\hat{p}] = p$, and since the $X_i$'s are i.i.d., we get that $\text{Var}[\hat{p}] = \dfrac{p(1-p)}{n}$.

For large $n$, the distribution of $\hat{p}$ can be approximated by a normal distribution with mean $p$ and standard deviation $\sqrt{\dfrac{p(1-p)}{n}}$.

Therefore, $\Pr[|p-\hat{p}| < 0.05p] \approx \Pr\left[-0.05\sqrt{\dfrac{np}{1-p}} < Z < 0.05\sqrt{\dfrac{np}{1-p}}\right]$, where $Z \sim N(0,1)$.

You can calculate this in terms of the normal cdf.

Comment: One thing that confuses me... Once you sum Bernoulli r.v.s, it becomes Binomial, no? So why use the variance of the Bernoulli in this computation? This is something that has always confused me.

Comment: @JimmyK4542, isn't it odd that the probability of $p$ within the depends on $p$? Because if $p$ is known, then the probability of it within the interval is 1. I feel I am missing a link here, what's the proper way to think about it?

Comment: Well, I have investigated more, and there are a few ways to get rid of the dependency of $p$, and approximate with a broader interval.

Comment: @zyxue it's very well explained in the book from howard g tucker https://www.math.uci.edu/people/howard-tucker. The probability we are computing here is not the probability of p being within some interval, p is not a stochastic variable, it's a number. What we are computing is the probability of observing \hat p within p+/-0.05p

Comment: @StefanoFalasca Thank you. Would you mind give the name of that book. The link sees not available.

Comment: @StefanoFalasca Is it "SOME THEORY AND PRACTICE OF STATISTIC", if yes, which chapter is it?

Comment: @WXJ96163 I have a paper version of the book and it's called "An introduction to probability and mathematical statistics". You should be able to find the pdf if you search for "Howard Tucker statistics" on google

Answer (score 0):

Continuing JimmyK4542's answer, the probability of the interval is still a function of $n$, and $p$, so I plotted the probability as a function of $n$ (how many tosses) for different possible $p$ between 0.4 and 0.6, we could see that to ensure the inequality in the question holds, $n$ > 2300.

In general, the smaller the $p$ is, the larger the $n$ needs to be to ensure $\text{Pr}(|p - \hat p| < 0.05p)$, which makes sense as e.g. $0.05 \cdot 0.1 = 0.005$, which is much smaller a cutoff than $0.05 \cdot 0.9 = 0.045$.

Instead, it may be more useful to constrain by $\text{Pr}(|p - \hat p| < c)$, which c is a constant cutoff, e.g. 0.01, i.e. the real $p$ and estimated $\hat p$ only differ by 0.01 at max.

[image]

An zoom out version of the plot

[image]

Plotting code:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

matplotlib.style.use('classic')

import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats

def cdf(n, p):
    factor = np.sqrt(n * p / (1 - p))
    return stats.norm.cdf(0.05 * factor) - stats.norm.cdf(-0.05 * factor)

ns = np.arange(1, 3000)
ps = np.arange(0.4, 0.61, 0.05)
for p in ps:
    plt.plot(ns, cdf(ns, p), label=f'p={p:.2f}')

plt.plot(ns, np.repeat(0.95, ns.shape[0]), color='black')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.grid()
plt.ylabel('Pr')
plt.xlabel('n')
```